# Update DataGridView Data Using DataView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a textbox that I'm using to search a customer from my database.

this is my code :

```
DataView dv = new DataView(tabSearchCustomer);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT({0},System.String) LIKE '%{1}%'", "ID", txtboxSearchCustomer.Text);
dgvCustomers.DataSource = dv;
```

dgvCustomers.DataSource = dv only shows the new data , it doesn't replace it in the dgv.

I want that my dgv will updated with the new data I was searched (**replace the old data in the dgv**) , how can I do that ?

My dgv before the search :
[image]

My dgv after the search : [image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - are you expecting the `DataGridView` to be updated when you update the `DataSource`?

Comment: Yes , i want that my dgv will  **only** contain this data : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHW0E.png

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string storedProcedure, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(DLLConfig.GetDataBaseConnection()))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ExecuteQuery().DefaultView;
```

Comment: I'm using OleDb not SQL.